# Product description not displayed properly on WordPress front end

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't display the product description properly in the WordPress front-end product page with its styles given in the editor.

Given below is the code I used to display the description. It's working fine but its not taking the style.

```
<?php echo stripslashes_deep($row_pro->proDescription); ?>
```

Comment: anybody please help me. I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution. Given below is the code which help me to solve.

`<?php  $desc = stripslashes_deep($row_pro->proDescription);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $desc); 
            echo $content; ?>`